# The Galerkin Method without inner-product property

Tags: functional-analysis, numerical-methods

Suppose you are dealing with a differential equation of the form $L (u) = f \text{ on } \Omega$, with some differential operator $L$. Let us define
\begin{align}
\langle u,v \rangle_L = \int_\Omega u L(v) \mathrm{d} \Omega
\end{align}
and let us assume that $L$ satisfies all necessary conditions for $\langle , \rangle_L$ to be an inner-product, i.e. linearity, symmetry and positive-definiteness. Let $\Sigma = \{w_1,\ldots,w_n\}$ be a (linearly independent) basis. It is quite easily seen that the vector $\mathbf{c}$ that solves the system
\begin{align}
\forall i \in \{1,\ldots,n\}: \sum_j c_j \int_\Omega w_i L(w_j) \mathrm{d} \Omega = \int_\Omega w_i f \mathrm{d} \Omega
\end{align}
contains the $\{c_j\}$ that minimize
\begin{align}
\|u^* - \sum_j c_j w_j \|_L,
\end{align}
where $u^*$ is the exact solution of $L(u) = f$.

Now suppose that $L$ does not satisfy above properties. I have seen in many applications, in particular non-linear problems, that the Galerkin method is nevertheless used. I am wondering, however, whether one can expect good results from it, since above principle does not hold anymore. What am I exactly minimizing when $\langle , \rangle_L$ is not an inner product, is there a theorem that states that $\sum_j c_j w_j$ converges to the exact solution in some norm if we let the amount of basis functions go to infinity ?

On what grounds, exactly, does the Galerkin produce approximations that can be considered 'good' in this case ?